# Representation of a Gradual underflow program

Tags: c++, c, linear-algebra

I was reading about the gradual underflow concept and how it is op important in the music industry [Gradual overflow Application in Music](http://www.cs.rice.edu/~taha/teaching/05F/210/Labs/Lab07/gradualUnderflow.html)

I well understand the problem of an overflow buffer, but this i don't know how to represent an underflow.

Can you please give me an example(a program preferably in c or c++) as in how a computer handles gradual underflow?

Comment: That article is total nonsense.

Comment: here ya go https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow

Comment: Yes i have already gone through that link. That link doesn't solve the problem. I need a code snippet to understand fully.

Comment: Gradual underflow WTF?   Is that some sort of anti-clipping algorithm?   Either way, no code snippet, because it's a system design issue.

Comment: @MartinJames - Gradual Underflow is a thing. Look at Denormalized Numbers in the artcile if you want something more scientific. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19422-01/819-3693/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: This isn't really the right question to ask, the part of the computer that deals with gradual underflow is the hardware. It's a part of the IEEE754 spec. I can't really show code as such.

Answer (score 0):

Gradual underflow is related to what IEEE 754 calls "subnormal" numbers.

Consider using scientific notation in which you have (say) 10 digits of precision and exponents that can range from -99 through 99.

Under normal circumstances, you treat everything as scientific notation, so if you want to represent 1000, you represent it as 1e3 -- that is, 1 * 10<sup>3</sup>.

Now, consider a number like 1.234e-102. The smallest exponent you can represent is -99. So, if you do your job the simplest possible way, you simply that since it has an exponent smaller than that, it's just 0. That would be "fast underflow".

In IEEE 754 (and related standards) you can store that as (essentially) 0.001234 * 10<sup>-99</sup>. In doing so, you may lose some precision compared to a normal number that has an exponent in the -99...99 range. On the other hand, you lose *less* than if you just rounded it to zero because it has an exponent smaller than -99. In fact, in this case it started with 4 significant digits, and as represented it retains all 4 significant digits.

On a computer, the numbers are represented in binary, so the numbers of significant digits and/or maximum range of exponents aren't round numbers when converted to decimal, but the same basic idea applies--when we have a number that's too small to represent in the normal format, we can still store it with the smallest exponent that *can* be represented, but also includes some leading zeros.

This does lead to one difficulty: numbers are normally stored in what's called normalized form. The "significand" part is normalized by shifting it left until the first digit is a 1 (keep in mind that since it's binary it can only be 0 or 1). Since we know it's a 1, we cheat a little: we don't normally store that 1 in the number as it's stored. So, a double precision floating point number normally has 53 bits of precision, but only actually *stores* 52 bits of significand.

With a subnormal number, that's no longer the case. That's not terribly *difficult* to deal with, but it still introduces a special case--and one that's only rarely used, so CPU designers (and such) rarely try to optimize for it. As a result, the exact same code can suddenly run a *lot* slower when executing on data that contains subnormals.