# Graceful Underflow

Tags: linear-algebra, scientific-computing, underflow

I have been searching about this for so long, but i am not able to understand what this question means.

**Question:**

```
Write a program in any language to determine how your computer handles graceful 
underflow.
```

I understand that a overflow condition is something like this:
if an integer can store a **maximum value of x** and if we assign a value of **x+1**,  the value **x+1** will be converted to the the lowest value the integer can hold. I understand that underflow is just the reverse. 

**How does it stand from High performance scientific computing / Linear algebra  point of view ?**

I have read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo) , but i think it's the same underflow/ overflow stuff that i mentioned above. What does the graceful underflow stand for?

Comment: Underflow happens when a floating-point number becomes too small. Meaning the negative exponent becomes too large. to find out how your system handles it divide the smallest number by 2. Still stump n the graceful part.

Comment: Try http://www.cs.rice.edu/~taha/teaching/05F/210/Labs/Lab07/gradualUnderflow.html

Comment: And this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111307/gradual-underflow-and-denormalized-numbers-in-ieee

Comment: Could you give me a program that demonstrates the same?

Comment: @King-Ink Yes, it is a known fact.

Comment: @BoyLittUp you just write a loop division to your underflow boundary and multiply it back to see the difference and precision lost.

Comment: @StoneBird Okay, but can you give an example as such?

Comment: @BoyLittUp what do you mean? I think the idea is pretty clear...You want me to write up the code? Or you want me to explain "How does it stand from High performance scientific computing / Linear algebra point of view"?

Comment: I know it has to do with bit manipulation if we are taking C as our language or try using sys.float_inf incase of python. However, i am looking for a code snippet that does the same.

Comment: @StoneBird The first like that you posted. Actually that link was deemed useless. here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642756/representation-of-a-gradual-underflow-program

Comment: @BoyLittUp as mentioned in that link, the software doesn't handle underflow. The hardware does. All you can do is to run some numerically unstable algorithm such that you observe a loss of precision...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay,as per the link posted by @StoneBird in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111307/gradual-underflow-and-denormalized-numbers-in-ieee) was particularly helpful. Here i have created a program in c that demonstrates the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned int s,e,m;
    unsigned int* ptr;
    float a,temp=0;
    a=1;
    float min=pow(2,-129);
    while(a>min){
        temp=a;
        a=a/2;
    }
    printf("Value=%e\n",temp);
    ptr=(unsigned int*)&temp;
    s = *ptr >> 31;
    e = *ptr & 0x7f800000;
    e >>= 23;
    m = *ptr & 0x07fffff;
    printf("sign = %x\n",s);
    printf("exponent = %x\n",e);
    printf("mantissa = %x\n",m);
    return 0;
}
```

Here the **min** variable is used to change the final number...i used min=pow(2,-129), pow(2,-128) and pow(2,-130) to see the results and the saw the [Denormal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number) number appear.This wiki page explains it all.

Comment: Kindly let me know your inputs on this.